# RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2: Unknown error occurred

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg, stream, rtmp

Here is the script I am trying to run, I believe the issue is in here:

```
#!/bin/bash


GIF=/home/stream1/85012216.gif
STREAM_KEY=thisisasecret
URL=rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2
FPS=30
KEYINT=$(expr $FPS \* 3)

$FFMPEG -f alsa -ac 2 -i hw:Loopback,1,0 -fflags +genpts -r $FPS -i $GIF \
-vcodec libx264 -x264opts keyint=$KEYINT:min-keyint=$KEYINT:scenecut=-1 -b:v 1000k \
-preset veryfast -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 854x480 \
-c:a libfdk_aac -b:a 96k -ar 44100 \
-f flv $URL
```

The error:

> ffmpeg version N-92337-g8e50215b5e Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
>   configuration: --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree
>   --enable-pthreads --enable-postproc --enable-libtheora --enable-version3 --enable-libx264 --enable-libfdk-aac --disable-stripping --disable-encoder=libschroedinger --enable-librtmp --enable-gnutls --enable-avfilter --enable-libfreetype --disable-decoder=amrnb --enable-fontconfig --disable-mips32r2 --disable-mipsdspr2 --disable-htmlpages --disable-podpages --disable-altivec --enable-libass --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi   libavutil      56. 23.100 / 56. 23.100   libavcodec     58. 36.100 /
>   58. 36.100   libavformat    58. 21.100 / 58. 21.100   libavdevice    58.  6.100 / 58.  6.100   libavfilter     7. 43.100 /  7. 43.100   libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100   libswresample   3.  4.100 / 
>   3.  4.100   libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100 Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo Input #0, alsa, from
>   'hw:Loopback,1,0':   Duration: N/A, start: 1541258646.286883, bitrate:
>   1536 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s Input #1, gif, from '/home/stream1/85012216.gif':   Duration: N/A,
>   bitrate: N/A
>       Stream #1:0: Video: gif, bgra, 500x281, 16.67 fps, 16.67 tbr, 100 tbn, 100 tbc **RTMP_ReadPacket, failed to read RTMP packet header
>   rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2: Unknown error occurred**

System details:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

Answer (score 1):

-f flv $URL should be -f flv $URL/$STREAM_KEY